# How can I find all interfaces of a class that are of certain super type in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Suppose this is the Kotlin code.

```kotlin
interface Command
interface Command1 : Command
interface Command2 : Command
interface Order


class Obj : Command1, Command2, Order
```

Then for the code above, the output should be `Command1` and `Command2` as I only want the result for a certain type which in this case is `Command`. Therefore, `Order` should not be the output.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    Obj().javaClass.interfaces.filter { Command::class.java.isAssignableFrom(it) }.forEach { println(it.simpleName) }
}

interface Command
interface Command1 : Command
interface Command2 : Command
interface Order


class Obj : Command1, Command2, Order
```

**Output**:

```
Command1
Command2
```